# Opening PDF file in my android app with the new Adobe Reader DC

Tags: android, pdf, adobe, reader

I have a problem with my app : before the release of the new Adobe Reader DC I used this code for open PDF files that are stored in my "assets" folder within my project

**SomeActivity.java**

```
@Ovveride
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    File fileDir = getFilesDir();
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {

        out = openFileOutput(fileDir.getName(), Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    Context ctx = this;

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.menu_tutorial)

        Utility.loadPDF(assetManager,fileDir,out,ctx,"Tutorial.pdf");


    if (id == R.id.menu_schedule) {

        Utility.loadPDF(assetManager, fileDir, out, ctx, "Lavoro.pdf");

    }

    if (id == R.id.menu_table) {

        Utility.loadPDF(assetManager, fileDir, out, ctx, "Tabella.pdf");

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```

**Utility.java**

```
public static void loadPDF (AssetManager assetManager ,File filesDir, OutputStream out, Context ctx, String path ) {

    InputStream in = null;
    File file = new File(filesDir, path);

    try {

        in = assetManager.open(path);

        copyFile(in, out);
        in.close();
        in = null;
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());

    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + filesDir + "/" + path),"application/pdf");


    ctx.startActivity(intent);

}
```

This worked very well, I could open my PDF files from every activity i wanted just by clicking on one of these three menu option.

With the new Adobe Reader DC installed, when I try to open the same files in the same manner i got this error fro Adobe Reader DC : "Unable to access this file. Check the path or the network and try again."

I don't know if something has changed or not with the new Adobe's app, but i can't open my PDF files anymore.

Comment: `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` was deprecated some time ago and was always a really bad idea. Either copy to external storage, or use `FileProvider` to serve from internal storage, or use [my `StreamProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider) to serve directly from `assets/`.

Comment: In the very first version of Adobe Reader DC for Android, it was only very difficult to open local files; as far as I remember, this has been fixed with the newest version. However, I don't know whether this is of great relevance to the current problem.